# Android-Tools Gradle Plugin 0.12 fails with error 'duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml'

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I am struggling with a build error when using Gradle with the Android-Tools Gradle plugin to compile a multi-project build. 2 of my projects fail to build with the error reported above.

Note that we have added additional elements to the Android manifest that we use. Essentially, our `AndroidManifest.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.xxx.yyy.zzz"
          android:versionCode="13"
          android:versionName="1.2.3">

  <uses-sdk
      .../>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.yyy.CONFIGURATION"/>

  <application
      ...>

    <activity
        ...>
        ...
    </activity>

    <activity
        ...>
        ...
    </activity>

  </application>

  <meta-data android:name="www" android:value="xxxx"/>
  <meta-data android:name="xxx" android:value="yyyy"/>
  <meta-data android:name="xxx" android:value="zzzz"/>

</manifest>
```

The error is being reported on the last 2 meta-data lines (at the bottom of the above example), where the `android:name` attributes are identical. My limited research has identified this to be valid XML. Unfortunately I have not been able to validate the schema as I understand that no schemas are published.

Extract from the build log:

```
:src:aaa:processDebugManifest
/xxx/aaa/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:36:3 Error:
    Element meta-data#xxx at AndroidManifest.xml:36:3 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:35:3
/xxx/aaa/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
:src:aaa:processDebugManifest FAILED
```

I have been using earlier versions of the Android-Tools Gradle Plugin with an identical Android manifest file and this has not caused an issue (last known working version 0.8).

**Question**: Can I add configuration to my `build.gradle` file to ignore this? Or would it be worthwhile raising as an issue on the Android-Tools repo?

Thanks

Comment: If you are stuck, while looking for a better solution, you can set `useOldManifestMerger true`in the `android { }` block. Btw, are you sure you can have two meta-data with the same name?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It worked perfectly and gives me an interim solution. You are right querying whether we can have the two meta-data with the same name. I am not sure. It certainly is regarded as acceptable XML. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any way of validating the XML with a Schema document.